Best way to avoid a loop
I have 2 dataframes  of number x and y of same length and an input number a. I would like to find the fastest way to calculate a third list z such as :

z[0] = a
z[i] = z[i-1]*(1+x[i]) + y[i]

without using a loop like that :
a = 213
x = pd.DataFrame({'RandomNumber': np.random.rand(200)})
y = pd.DataFrame({'RandomNumber': np.random.rand(200)})
z = pd.Series(index=x.index, dtype=float)
z[0] = a
for i in range(1,len(x.index)):
    z[i] = z[i-1]*(1+x.iloc[i]) + y.iloc[i]


shouldn't x,y be series?

This looks like a complicated operation that's hard to vectorized. numba should be helpful.

You can't really avoid the loop here because of the additions, if you try to develop the Series you'll see that there are x(i-1)*x(i)x(i+1)… factors

Related: cs95's answer on "How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame?" - It lists other options and has links to relevant documentation.

You can't really vectorize this function, the development of the operation becomes too complex.
For instance, z[i+1] expressed in function of z[i-1] is equal to:
z[i-1]*(1+x[i])+y[i] + z[i]*(x[i+1]+x[i]*x[i+1]) + y[i]*x[i] + y[i+1]

And this get worse for each step
As suggested in comment, if speed is a concern, you could use numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, x, y):
    out = [a]
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        out.append(out[i-1] * (1 + x[i]) + y[i])
    return out

out = pd.Series(f(213, x['RandomNumber'].to_numpy(), y['RandomNumber'].to_numpy()), index=x.index)

Output (using np.random.seed(0) and with 5 rows):
0     213.000000
1     365.772922
2     587.139217
3     908.025165
4    1293.097825
dtype: float64

Timings (200 rows):
# python loop
59.8 ms ± 908 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# numba
151 µs ± 968 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


Thanks for the solution. numba seems very interesting. However, I do not understand your code relative to numba. My understanding for it to work is that there should be a decorator @jit before the loop.

@Fred of course! This is a copy/paste fail from my side ;)
